# angular.js - iElement is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement auto-complete using [autoComplete Directive](http://jsfiddle.net/swfjt/4935/).
Here is my `directive`:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

The error is `undefined is not a function` for `iElement`.
I had included `angular` and `jQuery` in my app but my angular version is `1.3` (unlike the example)is this is the reason? is so there is a fix for it?

Comment: Give us your example with error.

Comment: actually your example works without any error for me - http://jsfiddle.net/swfjt/4935/

Comment: It work fine with me :)

Comment: Thanks, found the problem in my jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap iElement with $(), like so

```
$(iElement).trigger('input');
```